# Dispose one existing data server connection for all SignalR hubs

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, signalr

I have a data server pushing data through my `.NET` server to clients using ?`SignalR`. Because a `SignalR Hub` instance is created per request, but I want only one connection / subscription to the data server, I'm using a singleton controller to manage and map incoming data to the corresponding client.

My problem now is: when and how can I dispose this one connection on application termination (even forced termination)?

I'm quite new to handling connections in `.NET` so this might be really easy. Maybe there's a better application design as using the singleton controller.